# Why isn't IDA Freeware using my .idt file?

Tags: ida

I'm trying to learn my way around IDA and using the IDA Free package. I've been trying to analyse a program that imports mfc140 which IDA Free doesn't ship signatures for.

I've loaded the .dll myself and used a small script to generate a .idt file which as far as I can tell is OK. However, when I load the IDT using the `File -> Load File -> IDS/IDT File...` dialog nothing happens.

I'm not entirely sure what I've gotten wrong here.

Heres a small sample of the program with the imports:

```
.idata:0000000140019618 ; __int64 __fastcall mfc140_265(_QWORD, _QWORD, _QWORD)
.idata:0000000140019618                 extrn __imp_mfc140_265:qword
.idata:0000000140019618                                         ; DATA XREF: mfc140_265↑r
.idata:0000000140019618                                         ; Import by ordinal 265
.idata:0000000140019620                 extrn __imp_mfc140_266:qword
.idata:0000000140019620                                         ; DATA XREF: mfc140_266↑r
.idata:0000000140019620                                         ; Import by ordinal 266
.idata:0000000140019628                 extrn mfc140_1639:qword ; CODE XREF: sub_140016210+9D↑p
.idata:0000000140019628                                         ; sub_1400165D0+3B↑p
.idata:0000000140019628                                         ; DATA XREF: ...
.idata:0000000140019628                                         ; Import by ordinal 1639
.idata:0000000140019630                 extrn mfc140_4937:qword ; CODE XREF: sub_140016340+38↑p
.idata:0000000140019630                                         ; sub_140016660+32↑p
.idata:0000000140019630                                         ; DATA XREF: ...
.idata:0000000140019630                                         ; Import by ordinal 4937
.idata:0000000140019638                 extrn mfc140_5656:qword ; CODE XREF: sub_140016210+72↑p
.idata:0000000140019638                                         ; sub_140016340+2D↑p ...
.idata:0000000140019638                                         ; Import by ordinal 5656
.idata:0000000140019640                 extrn mfc140_316:qword  ; CODE XREF: sub_140016070+2C↑p
.idata:0000000140019640                                         ; sub_140016070+37↑p
.idata:0000000140019640                                         ; DATA XREF: ...
.idata:0000000140019640                                         ; Import by ordinal 316
.idata:0000000140019648                 extrn mfc140_300:qword  ; CODE XREF: sub_1400161E0+20↑p
.idata:0000000140019648                                         ; DATA XREF: sub_1400161E0+20↑r
.idata:0000000140019648                                         ; Import by ordinal 300
.idata:0000000140019650                 extrn mfc140_310:qword  ; CODE XREF: sub_140001030+1B↑p
.idata:0000000140019650                                         ; sub_140001070+1B↑p ...
.idata:0000000140019650                                         ; Import by ordinal 310
```

And here is a slice of my `.idt` file.

```
0 Name=mfc140.dll
256 Name=??$CopyElements@VCOleVariant@@@@YGXPAVCOleVariant@@PBV0@H@Z
257 Name=??$HashKey@ABUtagVARIANT@@@@YGIABUtagVARIANT@@@Z
258 Name=??$HashKey@PB_W@@YGIPB_W@Z
259 Name=?HashKey@CMapStringToPtr@@QBEIPBD@Z
260 Name=??$HashKey@VCComBSTR@ATL@@@@YGIVCComBSTR@ATL@@@Z
261 Name=??$SerializeElements@V?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@@YGXAAVCArchive@@PAV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@H@Z
262 Name=??$SerializeElements@V?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@@YGXAAVCArchive@@PAV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@H@Z
263 Name=??$SerializeElements@VCComBSTR@ATL@@@@YGXAAVCArchive@@PAVCComBSTR@ATL@@H@Z
264 Name=??$SerializeElements@VCOleVariant@@@@YGXAAVCArchive@@PAVCOleVariant@@H@Z
265 Name=??_U@YAPAXI@Z
266 Name=??3@YAXPAX@Z
267 Name=??0?$CSimpleStringT@_W$00@ATL@@QAE@ABV01@@Z
268 Name=??0?$CSimpleStringT@_W$00@ATL@@QAE@ABV01@@Z
269 Name=??0?$CSimpleStringT@D$00@ATL@@QAE@PAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
270 Name=??0?$CSimpleStringT@_W$00@ATL@@QAE@PB_WHPAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
271 Name=??0?$CSimpleStringT@_W$00@ATL@@QAE@PB_WPAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
272 Name=??0?$CSimpleStringT@D$00@ATL@@QAE@ABV01@@Z
273 Name=??0?$CSimpleStringT@D$00@ATL@@QAE@ABV01@@Z
274 Name=??0?$CSimpleStringT@D$00@ATL@@QAE@PAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
275 Name=??0?$CSimpleStringT@D$00@ATL@@QAE@PBDHPAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
276 Name=??0?$CSimpleStringT@D$00@ATL@@QAE@PBDPAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
277 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@_WH@Z
278 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@ABUtagVARIANT@@@Z
279 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@ABUtagVARIANT@@PAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
280 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@ABV01@@Z
281 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@DH@Z
282 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PA_W@Z
283 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PBD@Z
284 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PBD@Z
285 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
286 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PA_W@Z
287 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PB_WH@Z
288 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PB_WHPAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
289 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PB_WPAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
290 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PBD@Z
291 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PBDH@Z
292 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PBDHPAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
293 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PBDPAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
294 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PBE@Z
295 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PBEPAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
296 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@XZ
297 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@_WH@Z
298 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@ABUtagVARIANT@@@Z
299 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@ABUtagVARIANT@@PAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
300 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@ABV01@@Z
301 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@DH@Z
302 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PA_W@Z
303 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PBD@Z
304 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PBD@Z
305 Name=??0?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
306 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PA_W@Z
307 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PB_WH@Z
308 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PB_WHPAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
309 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PB_WPAUIAtlStringMgr@1@@Z
310 Name=??0?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@QAE@PBD@Z
```

I'm absolutely certain I've missed some key detail but the documentation I've been able to find is pretty thin.